# How can I watch old episodes of Nova on my iPad?

Tags: ipad, applications, video, streaming, television

I've been trying to watch some old episodes of Nova on my iPad, but the Nova website only seems to stream the episodes using a Flash player. I think several seasons are available on iTunes, but paying $3.99 per episode for a free PBS show seems a little too expensive. I've also noticed the show is available on Hulu, but they only seem to provide the last couple of seasons.. The episode I'd like to watch is Secrets of the Samurai Sword from 2007, which is available on the PBS website but the iPad app only offers more recent episodes. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube is your friend, in this case - you can watch for free..

Use the built-in YouTube app and run a search for `Nova Secrets of the Samurai Sword.` While I don't have an iPad to try this on, I was able to bring up several instances of that particular video on my iPhone - I imagine that this method would also work on an iPad.

Here's one of the links if you'd like to check it out from a computer: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uMLG7FvDuCI

**Update (Nov. 2016)**:
Since full Nova videos are no longer available on YouTube, the only other option I've found is to go to PBS directly:

1. PBS Video app ([iTunes link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pbs-video/id398349296?mt=8))
2. Nova episodes list on the [PBS site](http://www.pbs.org/show/nova/episodes/)

However, to actually view the videos may require a membership/passport to your local PBS station (mine is KQED).

Comment: Nice find! I was looking for a more "official" source and didn't think to look on Youtube, but this will have to do. Thanks for your help. On a side note, watching content on an iPad is a legitimate issue faced by many iPad owners, so I'm not sure why this question has received so many down votes.

Comment: @user1457323, if you want something more legit, there is an official Nova channel on YouTube (http://www.youtube.com/show?p=rJP5gzeyV8g). Not quite sure how to get there via the iOS YouTube app though - I'll edit my answer if I figure it out.

Comment: Today it looks like there are zero full episodes of Nova on their YouTube channel. It's all previews and short things 5min or less.

Comment: @mikato, good point, Nova must've pulled their full videos from YouTube. I've updated my answer to provide the latest information I could find - the videos seem to only be available via PBS (and membership may be required).